# How to Use Array to Display Data in RecycleView Multi ViewHolder?

Tags: java, android

I want to use array to display data from `strings.xml` in a `RecycleView`  `multi ViewHolder`, it's okay when I display data without `array`, but if I use `array`, I get error in array code. Unfortunately the application has stopped. And the `logcat` is:

```
07-27 23:49:58.466 8159-8159/com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview/com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview.DoaSore}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview.DoaPagi.getData(DoaPagi.java:40)
        at com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview.DoaSore.onStart(DoaSore.java:28)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
07-27 23:54:58.846 8159-8159/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8159 SIG: 9
```

Can you fix this?

**DoaPagi.java**

```
public class DoaPagi extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doa_pagi);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    AdapterDoa adapter = new AdapterDoa(DoaPagi.getData());

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DoaPagi.this);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public static Context context;
public static List<ModelDoa> getData() {

    String[] data = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doasore);

    List<ModelDoa> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new ModelDoa("London", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
    list.add(new ModelDoa("Amsterdam", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
    list.add(new ModelDoa("Berlin", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));

    // error code is here
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        list.add(new ModelDoa(data[i], ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
    }

    return list;
}


}
```

**AdapterDoa.java**

```
public class AdapterDoa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<ModelDoa> mList;

public AdapterDoa(List<ModelDoa> list) {

    this.mList = list;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType) {

        case DOA_PAGI:
            View vieu = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_doa, parent, false);
            PagiViewHolder rcv = new PagiViewHolder(vieu);
            return rcv;

        case DOA_SORE:
            View doa = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_doa, parent, false);
            SoreViewHolder mdoa = new SoreViewHolder(doa);
            return mdoa;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ModelDoa object = mList.get(position);

    if (object != null) {

        switch (object.getType()) {

            case DOA_PAGI:
                ((PagiViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                break;

            case DOA_SORE:
                ((SoreViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mList == null)
        return 0;
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mList != null) {
        ModelDoa object = mList.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            return object.getType();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


}
```

**PagiViewHolder.java**

```
public class PagiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView mTitle;
public int posisi = 0;
public int posisi1 = 1;
public Button tombolbaca;
public Button tombolshare;

public PagiViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(mainViewClickListener);
    mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    tombolbaca = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonbaca);
    tombolshare = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonshare);
    tombolbaca.setOnClickListener(bacaClickListener);
    tombolshare.setOnClickListener(shareClickListener);
}

private View.OnClickListener bacaClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do button click handling here
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener shareClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do button click handling here
        if ( posisi == getAdapterPosition() ) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTitle.getText().toString() + mTitle.getText().toString() );
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share via");
            v.getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mainViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do button click handling here
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ssss = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};


}
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: it can't display data from array... Unfortunately the program has stopped.

Comment: Take a look at the Logcat and read the actual compile error.

Comment: 07-27 23:49:58.466 8159-8159/com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview/com.alexzh.tutorial.multiplerowlayoutsrecyclerview.DoaSore}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code above with code below, it's work:

```
public static List<ModelDoa> getData() {

String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doasore);

List<ModelDoa> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new ModelDoa("London", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
list.add(new ModelDoa("Amsterdam", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
list.add(new ModelDoa("Berlin", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));

// error code is here
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    list.add(new ModelDoa(data[i], ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
}

return list; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lays here:

```
String[] data = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doasore);
```

You're using `context` variable that is `null` since it has not been initialized. 
One possible solution will be the following:

```
public class DoaPagi extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doa_pagi);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        AdapterDoa adapter = new AdapterDoa(getData(this));

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DoaPagi.this);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static List<ModelDoa> getData(Context context) {

        String[] data = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doasore);

        List<ModelDoa> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new ModelDoa("London", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
        list.add(new ModelDoa("Amsterdam", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
        list.add(new ModelDoa("Berlin", ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));

        // error code is here
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            list.add(new ModelDoa(data[i], ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sa'ad Abdurrazzaq is the answer helping?

Comment: still NullPointerException?

Comment: yes,, you can try to run that's code below https://github.com/seadclark/multipleviewholders

Comment: I used your repo together with my suggestion and I don't get any NPE

Comment: NPE? What it mean? So, how about problem? What's solution?

Comment: NPE stands for null pointer exception. The solution is the code I provided as an answer to your question. What do you think?

Comment: Hi,, all thanks for your help. It works now. Yesterday,that's code doesn't work because file string.xml I have copied contain w820dp,I didn't realize that.