# How to Compare Two String and count them?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to count clicks based on getAdapterPosition(). And it works properly. Below the code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Do button click handling here
        if ( posisi2==getAdapterPosition() ) {
                clickcount--;
                tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + clickcount + "x");

                if (clickcount <= 0)
                {
                    mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

        } // adapter

    } // onClick
```

But when I am trying to count clicks using the comparison of two string, I got the problem. The result is, the computer can only count that once. Can you help me to fix the problem? The problem lays here:

```
public Button tombolbaca;
private int klik10 = 10;

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         tombolbaca = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonbaca);
        // Problem here
        if( tombolbaca.getText().toString().equals("Baca 10x") ) {
            klik10--;
            tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + klik10 + "x");

            if (klik10 <= 0)
            {
                mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }


    } // onclick
```

Comment: is the text of tombolbaca exactly "Baca 10x"?

Comment: yes, exactly "Baca 10x"

Comment: added an answer with an explaination, I think I got your problem, tell me if it is ^^

Comment: what is `posisi2` ? can you please provide the complete code.

Comment: I think we should understand his question first, both the code is same using `adapterPosition` and `string` comparison. Only the mysterious part is `posisi2`. We should have to understand what it is. @Sa'ad Abdurrazzaq can you please share the code relatively.

Comment: The complete code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567765/how-to-use-array-to-display-data-in-recycleview-multi-viewholder

Comment: @KrishnaSharma: This is continuation of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675048/how-to-delete-item-without-delete-position-in-recycler-view

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq Thank you for the update, if possible can you please share the layout screenshot how your row look like.

Comment: I'll tell you..

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675048/how-to-delete-item-without-delete-position-in-recycler-view/51676363#51676363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it now.

The problem is in logics: this is your code, written by text instead of code

```
    if( tombolbaca.getText().toString().equals("Baca 10x"){ // this line says "if the text is exactly Baca 10x, go on"
        klik10--; // this line says: "make the value of klik10 = klik10 -1
        tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + klik10 + "x"); //this line says "set text of tombolbaca as the composition of the strings and the value of klik10

        if (klik10 <= 0) //if klik10 is equal or less than 0, do this
        {
            mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

So, the problem lays here:

First iteration:

```
klik10 = 10
it enter the first if
klik10 will now be 9
text will be Baca 9x
not less than 1, so skip the if
```

Second iteration

```
klik10 = 9 (because you set it before)
not going into if
```

so, the problem is that you are going in only if text is Baca 10x, but after the first iteration it won't be that anymore.

A solution could be this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        klik10--;
        tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + klik10 + "x");

        if (klik10 <= 0)
        {
            mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

The if, as it is written, is not necessary. you can just remove it and the code will work.

If not, tell me why there is the if clause and I will fix above code :)

PS:

If you want to check if the text is the correct counter, do the following if:

```
if(tombolbaca.getText().String().equals("Baca " + klik10.toString() + "x"){
...
```

Comment: Actually I need a comparison of two string instead of getAdapterPosition(). So, if( tombolbaca.getText().toString().equals("Baca 10x") must be exist. FYI: Your answer has been answered and has been fixed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634673/how-to-stop-click-count-in-java-android)

But many thanks for your answer

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq I have one question (to answer correctly I need to understand a couple of things): exactly when do you want the if to be true? what is your exact aim?

Comment: Just forget it. I am go back to use getAdapterPosition() instead of equals()

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq I think it's better.. so chose an answer or delete the question if possible ^^

Comment: There is a continuation problem related this post, I'll tell you later.

Comment: This is continuation of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675048/how-to-delete-item-without-delete-position-in-recycler-view

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq honestly, reading the code, I think you should start with some tutorials.. you are lacking basic logics. go watching "Thenewboston" tutorial for Android on yt. all your problems are logic related and missing basic knowledges..

Comment: There are so many tutorials there,, can you give me a clue?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq [this is the best, in my opinion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y)

Comment: The problem is not because I am lacking basic logics. Actually, i have basic logics of this. The real problem is, because everyone can't understand what I mean,, If they understand what I mean, why they can't solve my problem until now?

Comment: Honestly you are lacking logica.. Because your problems are that you know what you want to do, but you don't know the logic steps to do. And also yes, its hard to understand you.. But for example in this question you tried to do "while value is greater then 1 (or similar, just an example) "using an == operator.. This is lacking of Basic logics of programming.. You need to learn if, while, for, excetera clauses, how they work and how to use those..then you can use this.. You can do what you want, but you should start with some tutorial.. And if noone can understand you, try to explain better..

Comment: Ok,, if you see the problem lays here, and you suggest me to read and learn many java tutorials, honestly man, if I follow your instructions, it will spent 6 months or over to mastering Java. If I am lacking logic, of course, I can't read a bunch of code, I can't modify many lines of code? But the question is: "Why I can? Why I can read a bunch of code? and why I can modify many lines of code?" FYI: I learn and got many things after I read and modify many codes.

Answer (score 0):

In second attempt the comparation will be between `"Baca 9x".equals("Baca 10x")` and your if statement not will work

Try as follow

```
if( !tombolbaca.getText().toString().equals("Baca 0x") ) { //using "Baca 0x"
    ...
}
```

Comment: this will never get in, since first time text is "Baca 10x", so klik10 will never decrease

Comment: I'm so sorry! I edited with operator `!` now

Comment: @AbnerEscócio: Thanks for your answer. Your code is work. But it cant get a specific object. So, all objects will be caught using your code. Imagine if we have many objects, 7x, 8x, 6x, so thats code cant be implemented in many objects