# How to Delete Item Without Deleting Position in Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I really need your help. I've searched Google many days with many keywords, but I couldn't get it. So, I decided to ask to you.

So, here it is. Actually, I have one button in RecyclerView, but this button is repeated as much amount of data available, there are: Button with text "Baca 3x", "Baca 4x", and so on. I want, if I click button with text "Baca 3x" 3 times, it will change to "Baca 2x" >> "Baca 1x" >> remove item. Also if I click button with text "Baca 4x" 4 times, it will change to "Baca 3x" >> "Baca 2x" >> "Baca 1x" >> remove item.

But my problem is, I can't treat every button with different treatment, because every time the item has been deleted, position of data changes automatically. Because of this, I can't get specific button. For example: There is two button,

```
 1. Button "Baca 3x" on position 0
 2. Button "Baca 4x" on position 1
```

If button "Baca 3x" on position 0 has been deleted, so button "Baca 4x" changed it's position automatically to 0. The problem lays here.

Until now I just get every button based on their positions, which is a problem for me. Because of this I am thinking about How to Delete Item Without Deleting Position in Recycler View? Can you guys solve my problem? Should I use DiffUtil?And how to use it? Below the complete code I use:

**ModelDoa.java**

```
public class ModelDoa {

public static final int DOA_PAGI = 0;
public static final int DOA_SORE = 1;
public static final int DOA_MASJID = 2;
public static final int DOA_BANGUNT = 3;
public static final int DOA_MAU_TIDUR = 4;

private String mName;
private String bName;
private int mType;

public ModelDoa(String name, String butong, int type) {
    this.mName = name;
    this.bName = butong;
    this.mType = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.mName = name;
}


public int getType() {
    return mType;
}

public void setType(int type) { this.mType = type; }


public String ambilName() {
    return bName;
}

public void setNama(String butonk) {
    this.bName = butonk;
}

}
```

**AdapterDoa.java**

```
public class AdapterDoa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public List<ModelDoa> mList;

public AdapterDoa(List<ModelDoa> list) {

    this.mList = list;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType) {

        case DOA_PAGI:
            View vieu = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_doa, parent, false);
            PagiViewHolder rcv = new PagiViewHolder(vieu, this);
            return rcv;

        case DOA_SORE:
            View doa = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_doa, parent, false);
            SoreViewHolder mdoa = new SoreViewHolder(doa);
            return mdoa;

        case DOA_MASJID:
            View dMasjid = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_doa, parent, false);
            MasjidViewHolder mMasjid = new MasjidViewHolder(dMasjid);
            return mMasjid;

        case DOA_BANGUNT:
            View dBangunt = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_doa, parent, false);
            BanguntViewHolder mBangunt = new BanguntViewHolder(dBangunt);
            return mBangunt;

        case DOA_MAU_TIDUR:
            View regut = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_doa, parent, false);
            MauTidurViewHolder turu = new MauTidurViewHolder(regut);
            return turu;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ModelDoa object = mList.get(position);

    if (object != null) {

        switch (object.getType()) {

            case DOA_PAGI:
                ((PagiViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                ((PagiViewHolder) holder).tombolbaca.setText(object.ambilName());
                break;

            case DOA_SORE:
                ((SoreViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                ((SoreViewHolder) holder).tombolbaca.setText(object.ambilName());
                break;

            case DOA_MASJID:
                ((MasjidViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                ((MasjidViewHolder) holder).tombolbaca.setText(object.ambilName());
                break;

            case DOA_BANGUNT:
                ((BanguntViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                ((BanguntViewHolder) holder).tombolbaca.setText(object.ambilName());
                break;

            case DOA_MAU_TIDUR:
                ((MauTidurViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                ((MauTidurViewHolder) holder).tombolbaca.setText(object.ambilName());
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    mList.remove(position); // hapus list
    notifyItemRemoved(position); // hapus tampilan
    // notifyItemRangeChanged( position, mList.size());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mList == null)
        return 0;
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mList != null) {
        ModelDoa object = mList.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            return object.getType();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


}
```

**PagiViewHolder.java**

```
public class PagiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView mTitle;
public Button tombolbaca;
public Button teksbaca;
public Button tombolshare;
private RelativeLayout rl2;
private int klik10 = 10;
private AdapterDoa myAdapter;

public PagiViewHolder(View itemView, AdapterDoa myAdapter) {
    super(itemView);
    this.myAdapter = myAdapter;

    itemView.setOnClickListener(mainViewClickListener);
    mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    tombolbaca = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonbaca);
    tombolshare = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonshare);
    tombolbaca.setOnClickListener(bacaClickListener);
    tombolshare.setOnClickListener(shareClickListener);
    rl2 = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relmasjid);
}

private View.OnClickListener bacaClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        teksbaca = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonbaca);

        // Baca 10x
        if( getAdapterPosition() ==0 ) {
            klik10--;
            teksbaca.setText("Baca " + klik10 + "x");

            if (klik10 <= 0)
            {
                // modify listItems however you want... add, delete, shuffle, etc
                myAdapter.deleteItem(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }

    } // onclick
};

private View.OnClickListener shareClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do button click handling here
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTitle.getText().toString() + "\n \n download aplikasinya di: http://www.tauhid.or.id" );
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share via");
            v.getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mainViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do button click handling here
    }
};


}
```

**DoaPagi.java**

```
public class DoaPagi extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doa_pagi);

    // toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //this line shows back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    List<ModelDoa> rowListItem =  getData();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DoaPagi.this);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    AdapterDoa rcAdapter = new AdapterDoa(rowListItem);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

}

private List<ModelDoa> getData() {

    String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doapagi);
    String[] baca = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bacapagi);

    List<ModelDoa> list = new ArrayList<ModelDoa>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            list.add(new ModelDoa(data[i], baca[i], ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI));
    }

    return list;
}

// Agar back button pada halaman induk settings berfungsi
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**UPDATE (FIX CODE) By:  [Krishna Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3503023/krishna-sharma):** 
https://github.com/seadclark/RecyclerViewWithButtonClicks

Comment: See the answer below, it might help

Comment: do yo have hardcoded read count in the string array
   `String[] baca = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bacapagi);` for example this string array might have items in any order say (1) Baca 5x (2) Baca 2x (3) Baca 10x and so on ?

Comment: yes,, I did. And it work,, all data list can show. But it not enough,, the button not working just use this way

Comment: I think I got your point, See the updated answer now

Comment: I'll try it,, many thanks @KrishnaSharma

Comment: @KrishnaSharma: Brother,, I need your explain please. I've updated the code in the post. But still getting error if position changed...

Comment: what error you getting, please explain in details

Comment: If position changes, then the number of clicks also changes. For example, I have two button:
1. Button 4x in poistion 0
2. Button  7x in position 1
After I click button 4x four times, if button 7x clicked, it will be 3x >> 2x >> 1x >> remove item. It's supposed to be 6x >> 5x >> 4x >> 3x >> 2x >> 1x >> remove item

Comment: If you click button 4x four times then it will get deleted and your list will have only one item i.e button 7x. is this correct ? if you click again on button 7x then it should be 6x,5x and so on. if not then definitely you are doing something wrong on click action. please share the code

Comment: My brother,, I've put the code in github. Maybe you can run the code and analyze the real problem directly. https://github.com/seadclark/RecyclerViewWithButtonClicks

Comment: Looked at the code, whenever you click on any button countdown starts with always 9,8,7.... . for example I clicked on button "READ 2X" then it starts counting like "READ 9X", "READ 8X" .... is this the issue ? it should had to "READ 1X". please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: As per your code it will always start countdown from 10 for each item, as you have hardcoded `private int read10 = 10;`

Comment: Updated the answer, verified myself. Working as expected now. Please review.

Comment: Ok, and I summon you in code update in post

Comment: You have accepted others answer not mine :(. please correct if you think so

Comment: I've changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix. just update the `ModelDoa` constructor as below. I have verified myself and working as expected now. **Also sent you pull request on github**.

```
public ModelDoa(String name, String butong, int type) {
    this.mName = name;
    this.bName = butong;
    this.mType = type;
    String[] data = butong.split("\\s");
    if (data.length > 0) {
        String count = data[1].substring(0, data[1].length() - 1);
        read10 = Integer.parseInt(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: error: no suitable method found for valueOf(Object)
method Integer.valueOf(String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to String)
method Integer.valueOf(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to int)

Comment: Also its not work. if I click the button it will be -1

Comment: what happens if you click for button let say baca 2 x. Make sure in onBindViewHolder you have called this `tombolbaca.setTag(""+position)`;

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq did you try the solution ? please share the observation by clicking any of the button. for example you start clicking on "Baca 2x"

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow,and I'll tell you. Also I'll post this in github

Comment: The idea I proposed in solution, your recyclerview items button should remember their clickCount. accordingly ask to button give thier clicked count and decrement the clickCount by 1 on each click. once click count become -1, item will get removed. This will be applicable for all list item.

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq please try once and share the observation, after that we can work on tomorrow. It will just give me an idea where is the issue now.

Comment: The issue is very complicated. I have no idea, how I explain to you. Maybe, you can try yourself after I post this in github

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq I believe solution should help to you, please try once and share the observation before leaving.

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq I have posted a note in answer block to just understand the requirement, please put the comment accordingly.

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq Updated the answer, verified myself. Working as expected now. Please review.

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq Awesome, please accept the answer and vote up. so that ticket get close.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the item from your list AND updating the interface, have two methods. One of them (deleteItem) will only delete the item and the other (deleteItemAndUpdate) will delete the item and update the interface.

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    mList.remove(position); // hapus list
}

public void deleteItemAndUpdate(int position) {
    mList.remove(position); // hapus list
    notifyItemRemoved(position); // hapus tampilan
}
```

In the future, you can decide whether you want to only remove the item from your list OR remove the item and update the UI.

**EDIT 1:**

You need to keep track of the amount of times that each item was clicked. We can call this value readCount. Every time that the item is clicked, we subtract 1 from this value. When this value reaches 0, we remove it from the list.

**ModelDoa:**

```
public class ModelDoa {

    private int readCount = 10;

    public int getReadCount() {
        return this.readCount;
    }

    public void setReadCount(int readCount) {
        this.readCount = readCount;
    }
}
```

**PagiViewHolder:**

```
private View.OnClickListener bacaClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        teksbaca = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonbaca);
        ModelDoa modelDoa = mAdapter.getItem(getAdapterPosition());

        if (modelDoa != null) {
            modelDoa.setReadCount(modelDoa.getReadCount() - 1);
            if (modelDoa.getReadCount() <= 0) {
                myAdapter.deleteItem(getAdapterPosition());
            }
            teksbaca.setText("Baca " + modelDoa.getReadCount() + "x");
        }
    }
};
```

**AdapterDoa:**

```
public ModelDoa getItem(int position) {
    if (position > -1 && position < getItemCount()) {
        return this.mList.get(position);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The idea is to set the readCount variable when you instantiate the object. You do not have multiple variables that do the same thing. You just change the single readCount variable to be either 7 or 10 when you are creating it and use the same getItem method when retrieving the model (not variable!) itself.

**ModelDoa:**

```
public class ModelDoa {

    private String name;
    private String butong;
    private int type;
    private int readCount;

    public ModelDoa(String name, String butong, int type, int readCount) {
        this.mName = name;
        this.bName = butong;
        this.mType = type;
        this.readCount = readCount;
    }

    public int getReadCount() {
        return this.readCount;
    }

    public void setReadCount(int readCount) {
        this.readCount = readCount;
    }
}
```

**DoaPagi:**

```
private List<ModelDoa> getData() {
    String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doapagi);
    String[] baca = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bacapagi);

    List<ModelDoa> list = new ArrayList<ModelDoa>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // Here is where you would set the value of readCount.
        list.add(new ModelDoa(data[i], baca[i], ModelDoa.DOA_PAGI, i));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I've tried
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    mList.remove(position); // hapus list
}
it can't delete item

Comment: What do you mean? It's not being deleted from the List? Could you add a Log statement to your deleteItem method and see if it is actually being executed?

Comment: If button start from 10, it will be 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1 and so on. This the results

Comment: I meant the results from the actual method call. Check my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry for disturbing you. But I really need your help. I've stuck many days here. 
I want explain to you a real problem. 
"Baca" is Indonesian language means in english is "Read". So, when the text of button is "Baca 3x", it mean read three times. And we can achieve three times, by click the button 3 times, so the button will change to Baca 2x >> Baca 1x >> remove item . Until here,, do you understand?

Comment: Imagine we have a bunch of lists that contain a words. And you should read every list of words with different read counts. For example, In the first row, you should read three times, after you read three times, the first list will be deleted. In second row, you should read 10 times, in 3rd row, you should read 5 times, and so on. Can you feel me?

Comment: I understand. You should store this "read count" in your data model as an integer and each time the model in the list is clicked, reduce the count by 1. When it reaches 0, remove it from the list using one of the methods in my answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean.a few days earlier I had thought,   But I cant write the code. Can you write me please?

Comment: Could you check my edit and see if it works for you? You have to add the code to your data model and edit the method in your view holder.

Comment: Ok,, i'll try it,, thank you for your help. Many thanks

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it goes.

Comment: You have to add that to your Adapter class. Check my edit.

Comment: it work properly.But unfortunately,, all buttons if clicked. it will do same action. for example, if button 5x clicked, it will be 9x >> 8x >> and so on. Also if button 2x clicked, it will be 9x >> 8x >> and so on

Comment: You have to set that in the model. I am hard coding it for demonstration purposes. It should be set when the data model is instantiated.

Comment: Feel free to ask for help if you need it, but make sure you understand what you are doing. Also, make sure to upvote/accept the answers that help you.

Comment: Brother,, I've updated the code in the post. But still getting error

Comment: Brother,, I need your explain please. I've updated the code in the post. But still getting error if position changed..

Comment: My brother,, I've put the code in github. Maybe you can run the code and analyze the real problem directly. https://github.com/seadclark/RecyclerViewWithButtonClicks

Comment: Code by  Krishna Sharma is working now https://github.com/seadclark/RecyclerViewWithButtonClicks Thank you brother,, the problem has solved

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!